# How do I find the area under the curve of the standard normal distribution that overlaps with the unit circle? (improve my method)

Tags: integration

I'm a beginner calculus student, and I'm trying to solve this problem just as a personal exercise. It isn't for a class and has no application. I've arrived at a final answer, but I'm sure that my method is not the most efficient, and it has some inherent margin of error. It should be possible to get an exact answer analytically right?

I've shown all my work with notes on desmos:

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rohl1ijq49

(I apologize if this format isn't preferred)

My method was as follows,

Step 1: Find the intersections of the normal distribution and the unit circle (found via plotting and refining a point that visually matches the intersection, so this is a source of error).

Step 2: Find the area under the curve of the normal distribution that falls within the x-values of the left and right intersections of the normal distribution and the unit circle.

$$
\int_{-0.9683...}^{0.9683...} \frac{e^{\frac {-x^2}{2}}}{\sqrt {2 \pi}}\ dx = 0.667126241029
$$

Step 3: Find the signed area under the curve of the unit circle that falls outside the x-value of one of the intersections.

I found this value by putting the unit circle into slope-intercept form and setting the y-intercept as (1 - [the x-value of the positive intersection]) and setting the interval of the integral as (0, [y-value of the intersection]).

$$
\int_{0}^{0.2496...} -0.9683... + \sqrt{1-x^2}\ dx = 0.00528546
$$

I'd imagine there's a simpler way to do this using a trig function.

Step 4: Multiply the value found in [step 3] by 2 and then add to the value found in [step 2].

My final answer was,

Area under the curve of the normal distribution that falls within the unit circle ${\approx 0.677697161}$

Calculations of integrals were done using the desmos interface or wolfram.

Beyond checking my work and improving my method, any general tips for things like terminology and notation would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your approach is valid, and fairly straightforward.  The actual value of the total area enclosed is $$0.6776971\color{red}{545493939284030810290316189046821887555} \ldots$$ where the red digits indicate a different value than the one you reported, presumably due to differences in numerical precision of your computations.

Analytically, the area is

$$2 \int_{x=0}^\kappa \frac{e^{-x^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \, dx + 2 \int_{x=\kappa}^1 \sqrt{1-x^2} \, dx = 1 - 2\Phi(-\kappa) + \arccos \kappa - \kappa \sqrt{1 - \kappa^2},$$
where $\Phi(z) = \Pr[Z \le z]$ is the cumulative distribution function of a standard normal random variable $Z$, and  $\kappa$ is the unique positive solution of the equation
$$x^2 + \frac{e^{-x^2}}{2\pi} = 1.$$  Thus $$\kappa = \sqrt{1 + W(-(2e\pi)^{-1})},$$ where $W(z)$ is the product log function satisfying $$z = W(z) e^{W(z)}.$$

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for. This analytical approach is beyond my comprehension  but I need to do some research about the methods you're using before asking more questions. Thanks again